# How to get multiple counts from multiple tables within a date range with MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, count

I have 4 tables and need to combine them all to get counts from each one within a date range.

The tables are:

- writers_info - profile data for the writer: name, address, etc.
- writer_contacts - the Writer's Contacts.
- writer_notes - notes the Writer wants to record.
- writer_reminders - notes and dates/times to remind the Writer of a task.

I need a query to create a table that shows these columns within a date range (the Contacts, Notes & Reminders tables each have a datetime when a row is added):

1. user_id
2. author_name
3. #of Contacts
4. #of Notes
5. #of Reminders

The query below works and all indexes are defined, but the server times out or crashes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.user_id, CONCAT(w.author_fname,' ',w.author_lname) AS author_name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM writer_contacts WHERE writer_id = w.user_id AND date_added BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59' ) AS contacts, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM writer_notes WHERE writer_id = w.user_id AND note_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59' ) AS notes, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM writer_reminders WHERE writer_id = w.user_id AND reminder_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59' ) AS reminders 
FROM writers_info w, writer_contacts c, writer_notes n, writer_reminders r
WHERE (w.user_id = c.writer_id AND c.date_added BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59')
OR (w.user_id = n.writer_id AND n.note_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59')
OR (w.user_id = r.writer_id AND r.reminder_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-22 23:59:59')
ORDER BY w.user_id
```

I don't want ALL the Writers... only the approx 10% of those who have created a Contact, Note or Reminder. Hence the date ranges in the WHERE clause in order to limit the results to those Writers.

Is there some other way to get these results that makes more sense or can be optimized better?

Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong and used LEFT JOINS instead of INNER JOINS and fixed the WHERE clause with the ANDs and ORs in the right places. Here's the final query that works:

```
SELECT w.user_id, CONCAT(w.author_fname,' ',w.author_lname) AS author_name,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM writer_contacts WHERE w.user_id = writer_id AND date_added BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-06-21' ) AS contacts, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM writer_notes WHERE w.user_id = writer_id AND note_date BETWEEN '2022-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-21 23:59:59' ) AS notes, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM writer_reminders WHERE writer_id = w.user_id AND reminder_date BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-06-21' ) AS reminders 
FROM writers_info w
LEFT JOIN writer_contacts c ON w.user_id = c.writer_id
LEFT JOIN writer_notes n ON w.user_id = n.writer_id
LEFT JOIN writer_reminders r ON w.user_id = r.writer_id
WHERE (c.date_added BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-06-21' OR n.note_date BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-06-21' OR r.reminder_date BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-06-21')
GROUP BY w.user_id
```

Comment: Use JOIN instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested answer (This question already has answers here:) is not quite the same, as I want to return only those writers from the 1st table who have added any Contacts, Notes OR Reminders. I do not want ALL writers... just the approx 10% who've done that... hence the date ranges in the WHERE clause to limit those Writers. But there must be a better way to do it. I just haven't figured it out yet. :(

Comment: Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong and used LEFT JOINS instead of INNER JOINS and fixed by WHERE clause with the ANDs and ORs in the right places. I put the final working query at the end of my original post.